How to efficiently map jooq records to kotlin domains
I have been searching for a solution for a few days now but I am struggling to find an approach that is efficient and generic.
The Jooq documentation as well as solutions online have not really given me the opportunity to grasp how to map records to objects
Jooq Records mapping seems a very good solution but I don't know how to implement it when it comes to complex object.
Consider the following:
data class Person(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val state: Boolean,
    val roles: List<Role> = emptyList(),
    val vehicle: Vehicle
)

data class Role(
    val id: String,
    val personId: String,
    val name:String,
    val description,
    val List<Authorization>
)

data class Authorization(val id:String, val roleId: String, val type:String)

data class Vehicle(val id: String, val personId: String,val name: String, val type: String)

This is my fun to read from the db using Jooq:
        val record = mysqlDSLContext.select()
            .from(PERSON)
            .leftJoin(ROLES).on(PERSON.ID.eq(ROLE.PERSON_ID))
            .leftJoin(VEHICLE).on(PERSON.ID.eq(VEHICLE.PERSON_ID))
            .fetchOne()

I want to map this into the Person data structure
With an object is easier but I am not sure what's the best way to approach this when I am retrieving data from multiple tables and want to put them in an object that has list and other objects.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Your Person and Vehicle data classes seem unrelated. What kind of data structure do you want to map them into? Also, that VEHICLE join doesn't really make any sense. Can you please update your question addressing these 2 issues?

I have modified my post, what I am addressing is how to retrieve those relationships. i.e person has many roles linked by persnoId and a person can have one vehicle object linked by personId

I could just repeat my comment :), but have you read it? I don't really know how to answer your question unless you address the concerns from my comment...

I am sorry, I am not entirely sure what you're asking now. I want to map them into the Person data structure I have earlier. Also I have made the changes to the code, which wasn't showing a relationship correctly before. My Person data structure should have a list of Roles and an object Vehicle. I hope that makes more sense :)

Well, you've addressed my questions with the latest edit...

You can map things in arbitrary ways from flat result sets using jOOQ's Collector API support if you wish to go down this route of using LEFT JOIN to denormalise your data, but quite likely these features are more suitable:

MULTISET to nest collections
ROW to nest records
ad-hoc converters to map between jOOQ types and your data classes

The example below will assume you're either:

Using the JavaGenerator, to profit from platform types
Using nullable values in your data classes

See issue #13999 regarding nullability in jOOQ/Kotlin
More assumptions:

You're using a more recent version of MySQL (8+)
You're using jooq-kotlin extension functions
You're using the latest jOOQ versions (3.19+)

val result: List<Person> =
ctx.select(
       PERSON.ID,
       PERSON.NAME,
       PERSON.STATE,
       multiset(
           select(
               PERSON.role.ID,
               PERSON.role.PERSON_ID,
               PERSON.role.NAME,
               PERSON.role.DESCRIPTION,
           )
           .from(PERSON.role)
       ).mapping(::Role),
       row(
           PERSON.vehicle.ID,
           PERSON.vehicle.PERSON_ID,
           PERSON.vehicle.NAME,
           PERSON.vehicle.TYPE
       ).mapping(::Vehicle)
   )
   .from(PERSON)
   .fetch(Records.mapping(::Person))


Thank you so much, that's clear. One more question please, if I had an object within an object, how would I approach that? I have edited my question and added a list of authorization under the Role object

@da_user_2023: You can nest to arbitrary depths
